# How to get date six month before current date in single line in Java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to get a date six month before from present date. The code that I tried is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
System.out.println(format.format(c.getTime()));
```

But I want to reduce this to a single line expression which I want to use in my Jasper report to put in parameter expression.

How can I reduce it to single line expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wrap this util method into a Utility class build the jar and put it in classpath of your iReport and whenever you are compiling this jrxml

Comment: Do you need the utility class when you fill the report as well?

Comment: yes , you would need at runtime as well when it is evaluting the compiled expression, @MadProgrammer thanks for correcting

Answer (score 9):

Using Java 8 you can do this in single line:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(6).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")));
```

If you cannot use Java 8 consider using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the previous date just do something like below where **total number of previous days are multiplied with `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`**

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Where, *7 days are subtracted from the current date.*

Calculate the number of days in service side & pass it as a parameter to above line of code to get the required previous date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not efficient. Need to counts days of 6 months every time.

Comment: Usually "six months before" does not mean the exact number of days. For example, six months before July 10th is January 10th (181 days difference in non-leap year and 182 days in leap year). Six months before December 10th is June 10th (183 days difference).

Comment: Yeah, I know number of days r not always equal but we can calculate these days from the current date in our service.

Comment: Yeah obviously we can calculate but it's tentative and needs to make calculation every-time as current day will change everyday. Your solution is the best when given that number of days you need to subtract.

Answer (score 1):

Use Joda library because of various shortcomings of the `Date` and `Calendar` classes

```
new DateTime().minusMonths(6).toDate();
```

In **Java 8** update following also will be good.

```
LocalDateTime.from(referenceDate.toInstant()).minusMonths(6);
```